# Concat 2 datas from json Angular ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I try to put data from another array into one part in table. 
My first json "names" :

```
[
        {
            "name": "AAAAAA",
            "down": "False"

        },

        {
            "name": "BBBBBB",
            "down": "True"
        },
        {
            "name": "CCCCC",
            "down": "False"
        }
]
```

Second json "data" :

```
[
         {
            "data": "35%"
        }
]
```

Javascript:

```
 var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.service('service', function($http, $q){
        this.getNames = function () {
            var names = $http.get('names.json', {cache: false});
            var datas = $http.get('data.json', {cache: false});
            return $q.all({datas,names});
        };

        });
    app.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope, service, $http) {
            var promise = service.getNames();
            promise.then(function (data) {
                $scope.names = data.names.data;
                $scope.datas = data.datas.data;
                $scope.namesanddata = $scope.names.concat($scope.datas);

                console.log($scope.namesplit);
                console.log($scope.datas);

            });
    });
```

Table in HTML :

```
div ng-controller="FirstCtrl"
     <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="name in namesanddata">
            <td>{{name.name}}</td>
             <td ng-if="name.down=== 'False'">{{name.down}}</td>
             <td ng-if="name.down !== 'False'">{{name.data}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

My problem -  `<td ng-if="name.down !== 'False'">{{name.data}}</td>`dont show in table. in console.log it concat to array like 4 object and probably by this it don't show in table next to `{{name.name}}`, but i don't know how to show `{{name.data}}` from another json in table instead `{{name.down}}`.
Thanks for answers in advance.

Comment: Is it `data` or `datas`?

Comment: data in json datas. I concat datas to names then i have 4 object's in names where fourth is  { "data": "35% } - data in datas @PritamBanerjee

Comment: "data" is the plural. The singular is "datum", but whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give you an output of:

```
AAAAAA  False
BBBBBB  35%
CCCCC   False
```

Remove this line from the Controller:

```
$scope.namesanddata = $scope.names.concat($scope.datas);
```

Then either:

**Solution 1 - Inline in the view**

Change your `ng-repeat` as follows:

```
<tr ng-repeat="name in names">
    <td>{{ name.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ (name.down === 'False') ? name.down : datas[0].data }}</td>
</tr>
```

**OR**

**Solution 2 - Keep the view clean by using a Filter**

```
app.filter('myFilter', function () {
    return function(items, datas) {
        var filtered = [];
        angular.forEach(items, function (i) {
            if (i.down !== "False")
                i.down = datas[0].data;
            filtered.push(i);
        });
        return filtered;
    }
});
```

Change your `ng-repeat` as follows:

```
<tr ng-repeat="name in names | myFilter: datas">
    <td>{{ name.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ name.down }}</td>
</tr>
```